# Blazor not refresh UI

Tags: c#, user-interface, blazor

I am starting with Blazor, I did a very small project with a table and a pagination component but when paging the results it is not refreshing the UI.

If I debug I see that when paging the results obtained are correct but the UI does not change.

I leave you my code to see if you can help me:

```cs
@page "/test"
@using BlazorPagination
@using System.Text.Json
@inject IJSRuntime js
@inject HttpClient http

<h3>TEST</h3>
        <table data-toggle="table" id="table">
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var t in _data.Results)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td scope="row">@t.Id</td>
                        <td>@t.Text</td>
                        <td>@t.Value</td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <JSFunction></JSFunction>

        <BlazorPager CurrentPage="@_data.CurrentPage"
                     PageCount="@_data.PageCount"
                     OnPageChanged="(async e => { _page = e; LoadTest(); })"
                     ShowFirstLast="false"
                     ShowPageNumbers="true"
                     VisiblePages="10"
                     FirstText="First"
                     LastText="Last" />
@code {
    List<Common.TestEntity> testList;
    private PagedResult<Common.TestEntity> _data;
    private int _page = 1;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        LoadTest();
    }

    void LoadTest()
    {
        HttpClient http = new HttpClient();

        var httpResponse = http.GetAsync($"https://localhost:44348/api/test").GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        if (httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var responseString = httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            testList = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Common.TestEntity>>(responseString,
                new JsonSerializerOptions() { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true });

            _data = testList.AsQueryable().ToPagedResult(_page, 10);
        }
        this.StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: The actual paging is now happening on the wrong side of the /api/test call. How many records does that return?

Comment: /api/test only returns 50 records, and when I debug, I see that that is OK

Comment: As a last resort you can replace `<tr>` with `<tr @key="t">` inside the foreach() loop.

Comment: mmm not working

Answer (score 1):

Use async :

```
OnPageChanged="(async e => { _page = e; await LoadTest(); })"
```

```
 protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
 {
       await LoadTest();
 }

 async ValueTask LoadTest()
 {
        HttpClient http = new HttpClient();

        var httpResponse = await http.GetAsync($"https://localhost:44348/api/test");
        if (httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var responseString = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            testList = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Common.TestEntity>>(responseString,
                new JsonSerializerOptions() { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true });

            _data = testList.AsQueryable().ToPagedResult(_page, 10);
        }

        // InvokeAsync forces the StateHasChanged to be executed on the UI thread.
        await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);

 }
```

Side note: [Task vs ValueTask](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/understanding-the-whys-whats-and-whens-of-valuetask/) (its almost 2021)

Comment: Also change OnInitialized to be complete.

Comment: `await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);` , I'm not sure the optimizer will eliminate the lambda.

Comment: @HenkHolterman It does.. But your right the wrapping in a lambda is not required.

Comment: I didn't look in the source of this pager but I'm pretty sure that InvokeAsync is not required at all. But it won't hurt either.

Comment: @HenkHolterman yeah I treated the response as unknown. Was not much information could only make assumptions. That's why I left the deserializing alone.